Alitum 25 interactive routing via creation working in one project but not another, why?
I'm new to altium.  I created a project and can add vias with cntl + shift + click or cntl + shift + mousewheel up/down.  But, I have another project that I downloaded from TI (reference design), but when I interactive route in that project I can't make a via.

Just realized that the problem was that at the bottom of the screen "(LS) layer select?" had only "top layers" selected, changing this to all layers allowed for via creation.
